# Laravel 5.2 - Intervation Image resize

Tags: php, laravel

i'm tryng to resize image of user profile, but i have this error:

> NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 96: Unable to init from given
>   binary data.

MY CONTROLLER

```
public function updateAvatar(Request $request){

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // if i insert here: retur $user_id it return: 1.jpg it work well, 
        // my form work well, before i tryed to upload without resize and it work well. 
        // i want save image uploaded with id user and extention 
        // here i'm tryng to resize it, i installed intervation and inserted class 

        $img = Image::make('images/users',$user_id);
        $img->resize(100, 100);
        $img->save('images/users',$user_id);        
        $user = new User;

         $user->where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)

              ->update(['image' => 'images/users/'.$user_id]);
        return redirect('account')->with('message-success', 'Immagine profilo aggiornata con successo!');

    }else{
        return redirect('account')->with('message-error', 'File non trovato');
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to supply two arguments to `Image::make()`, but it should only be given one. I think you might want to do e.g. `Image::make('images/users/'.$user_id)` instead? Or whatever your full path to the file is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I think you were trying to create an Image from a text string, or possibly something that doesn't exist. I don't have my code editor in front of me, so I can't test, let me know what you get?

```
public function updateAvatar(Request $request){

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $img = Image::make($request->file('image'));
        $img->resize(100, 100);
        $img->save('images/users',$user_id);        
        $user = new User;

        $user->where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)
             ->update(['image' => 'images/users/'.$user_id]);

        return redirect('account')->with('message-success', 'Immagine profilo aggiornata con successo!');

    } else{

        return redirect('account')->with('message-error', 'File non trovato');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateAvatar(Request $request){

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $base=base64_decode($request['image']);
        $img = Image::make($base)->save($path);
        $img->resize(100, 100);
        $img->save('images/users',$user_id);        
        $user = new User;

        $user->where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)
         ->update(['image' => 'images/users/'.$user_id]);

        return redirect('account')->with('message-success', 'Immagine profilo aggiornata con successo!');

      } else{

           return redirect('account')->with('message-error', 'File non trovato');

      }
 }
```

This will definitely solve your issue..